# Change size leftviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

is there a way to change the size of the left view controller of the splitviewcontroller? I tried resizing the table but it does not work, and it doesn't show the properties to set the width and height. or maybe make the rightviewcontroller bigger anything would help. 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The master view controller in a `UISplitViewController` has a fixed width of 320 points. It cannot be changed via public API.